# MySQL If Statement and Increment

Tags: mysql

I am having issues with a MySQL If statement that creates a group rank. here is the MySQL Statement:

```
SELECT EnCode, EnName, QuScore, 
@scorerank := IF(@currathlete = EnCode, @scorerank + 1, 1),
@currathlete := EnCode
FROM ranking ORDER BY EnCode, QuScore DESC
```

It currently gives the following output

```
'1004277','Ashe','1628','1','1004277'
'1004277','Ashe','1309','1','1004277'
'1004277','Ashe','1263','1','1004277'
'1004277','Ashe','648','1','1004277'
'1004277','Ashe','645','1','1004277'
'1004277','Ashe','1628','1','1004277'
'1015934', 'Sabina', '544', '1', '1015934'
'1015934', 'Sabina', '455', '1', '1015934'
'1015934', 'Sabina', '276', '1', '1015934'
'1015934', 'Sabina', '216', '1', '1015934'
```

What it should be doing is incrementing each of the '1' numbers by one for each row that has the same code, and then starting from 1 again when it sees a different code number (1004277, then 1015934 in this case)

Any help is appreciated as i have followed a number of examples online using the above method but seem to hit the same issue a this point.

Comment: give me an image of the result you need. is this what you mean '1004277','Ashe','1628','1','1004277', 1
'1004277','Ashe','1309','1','1004277' ,2
'1004277','Ashe','1263','1','1004277',3
'1004277','Ashe','648','1','1004277',4
'1004277','Ashe','645','1','1004277',5
'1004277','Ashe','1628','1','1004277',6
'1015934', 'Sabina', '544', '1', '1015934',1
'1015934', 'Sabina', '455', '1', '1015934',2
'1015934', 'Sabina', '276', '1', '1015934',3
'1015934', 'Sabina', '216', '1', '1015934',4

Comment: Hi, Yes the result should look like the following (the fourth collumn is the rank number that needs incrementing):                   '1004277','Ashe','1628','1','1004277'
'1004277','Ashe','1309','2','1004277'
'1004277','Ashe','1263','3','1004277'
'1004277','Ashe','648','4','1004277'
'1004277','Ashe','645','5','1004277'
'1015934', 'Sabina', '544', '1', '1015934'
'1015934', 'Sabina', '455', '2', '1015934'
'1015934', 'Sabina', '276', '3', '1015934'
'1015934', 'Sabina', '216', '4', '1015934'
Thanks

Comment: i got a solution of your problem.. are you still there?@Robert

Comment: https://janac.medium.com/if-statements-in-mysql-conditional-logic-7e5acab4e8a8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way in stored Procedure:

```
drop PROCEDURE if EXISTS INCREMENTME;
create PROCEDURE INCREMENTME() 
BEGIN

DECLARE OldEnNamevar VARCHAR(10) DEFAULT NULL;
DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
DECLARE Encodevar VARCHAR(10);
DECLARE EnNamevar VARCHAR(10);
DECLARE QuScorevar VARCHAR(10); 
DECLARE scorerankvar VARCHAR(10);
DECLARE currathalthletevar VARCHAR(10);
DECLARE countcode int(29) DEFAULT(1);
DECLARE counter int(20) default 0;

DECLARE  get_cur  CURSOR FOR select `Encode`,`EnName`,`QuScore`,`scorerank`,`currathalthlete` from tbl_ranking;
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLSTATE '02000' SET done=1;
drop table if exists temp_temptable;
create TEMPORARY table temp_temptable(Encodevar VARCHAR(50) NULL,EnNamevar VARCHAR(50)  NULL,QuScorevar VARCHAR(50)  NULL,scorerankvar VARCHAR(50)  NULL,currathalthletevar VARCHAR(50)  NULL,recordCount int(10)  null);

OPEN get_cur;

REPEAT

set counter = counter + 1;
        FETCH get_cur INTO Encodevar,EnNamevar,QuScorevar,scorerankvar,currathalthletevar;


        if (OldEnNamevar = EnNamevar) THEN

            set countcode = countcode +1;

        ELSE
            if(counter=1) then
                                set countcode = 1;

            ELSE
                    set countcode = 0;
            end if;

        end if;

        if (OldEnNamevar != EnNamevar) THEN
            set countcode = 1;
        end if;

    if(OldEnNamevar=NULL) then
                    set countcode = 1;
    end if;


insert into temp_temptable (Encodevar,EnNamevar,QuScorevar,scorerankvar,currathalthletevar,recordCount) values(Encodevar,EnNamevar,QuScorevar,scorerankvar,currathalthletevar,countcode);
set OldEnNamevar = EnNamevar;


UNTIL done END REPEAT;

select * from temp_temptable;

drop temporary table if exists temp_temptable;
CLOSE  get_cur;




END
```

call the procedure like this:
call INCREMENTME();

Here's the result:
[image]

Comment: Thanks @reds That solution works perfectly and sits nicely in a stored Procedure, which is a better way of achieving what i needed.

Answer (score 1):

You have to initialize your variables, otherwise they are `null` (at least at the beginning of the session, probably not anymore if you run it twice), and your query will give strange results. Try

```
SELECT EnCode, EnName, QuScore, 
    @scorerank := IF(@currathlete = EnCode, @scorerank + 1, 1),
    @currathlete := EnCode
FROM ranking, (select @currathlete := '', @scorerank := 0) init
ORDER BY EnCode, QuScore DESC
```

Comment: Thanks @solarflare thats working too, i didn't realise they needed to be initialized